# Wine 1.6 from default repository has tiny fonts

Tags: wine, fonts, display-resolution, hdpi

Although there are instructions for adding PPA and installing Wine 1.7, Wine 1.8.5 and others claim Wine 1.9.8 will be best for the Mass Effect 3 game I want to play I nonetheless installed the Ubuntu 16.04 default using:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

Unfortunately when I call up the wine program via Dash I get a terribly tiny window with tabs I can't read without a magnifying glass and reading glasses:

[image: Wine DPI]

I've intentionally captured the window over a normal reading screen which has Unity Tweak Tool set at 1.5 x scaling and Google Chrome set a 110% magnification which are comfortable at 1920x1080 on 17" laptop screen 3 feet away. Hopefully you can decipher how tiny Wine is in real life.

I found one question here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/711012/wine-menu-fonts-are-too-small) where the only answer recommended not using the wine that Ubuntu installs by default. Feeling that other versions are not supported (like others promote about kernels here) I'd like to stick with the repository.

Doesn't anyone know where to set the DPI on this wine screen and perhaps all the others I might encounter down the road?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configure that in the **Wine configuration** option. Open terminal and run `winecfg` command to open Wine configuration dialog, then go to the **Graphics** tab and set the Screen Resolution slider.  Once configured, relaunch **Wine configuration** and you should be at your new DPI.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Changed it from 96 dpi to 214 and it works like a charm. Thank you @Terrance.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You're welcome!  I have problems seeing those small fonts too, so it works great for me as well.  Too bad our eyes aren't like wine and get better with age.  =)

Comment: @Terrance - Lol :)